# How to pass a razor view modal property value to a javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i try to send razor value to jquery funcion.

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumTransportado, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", id = "NumTransResp" + Model.ServicosID + "", name = "NumTransResp" + Model.ServicosID + "", onchange = "PreencheDadosVendedor(this, 3, " + @Model.ServicosID + ")" })
```

i can use all parameters except `" + @Model.ServicosID + "`

Js file:

```
function PreencheDadosVendedor(idVend, tipoFuncionario, idServicoEdicao) {
$.getJSON("/Contrato/getDadosVendedor", { id: $(idVend).val(), tipoFuncionario: tipoFuncionario },
  function (result) {
      switch (tipoFuncionario) {
          case 1:
              $("#NomeVendedor_Contrato").val(result.NomeVendedor);
          case 2:
              $("#NomeTransResponsavel").val(result.NomeVendedor);
          case 3:
              $("#NomeTransResponsavel_" + idServicoEdicao + "").val(result.NomeVendedor);
      }
  });
}
```

i try to do `idSericoEdicao` is my `@Model.ServicosID`, but i have same result: undifined

Comment: And does `@Model.ServicosID` actually have a value in your view model?

Comment: Yes, have value. I use it several times

Comment: View the source of the HTML page (in browser), find that onchange attribute. What does it look like?

Comment: it looks fine, do what i want

Comment: The html in browser:

`<input class="form-control input-sm" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NumTransportado must be a number." id="NumTransResp683" name="NumTransportado" onchange="PreencheDadosVendedor(this, 3, 683)" type="text" value="4">`

The 683 it value i want

Comment: So it looks fine, so your problem is elsewhere. Which part of your code is produce `undefined`? If you put `console.log(idServicoEdicao);` as the first line of your `PreencheDadosVendedor`, what does it output?

Comment: if i do `alert(idServicoEdicao);` in function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting undefined (Assuming value is a string) is because you need to wrap `@Model.ServicosID` it in quotes, otherwise it will look for the value of the property as the name of the variable, instead you just need to pass the value as the a string.

Try this:-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumTransportado, 
                  new { @class = "form-control input-sm", 
                    id = "NumTransResp" + Model.ServicosID + "", 
                    name = "NumTransResp" + Model.ServicosID + "", 
                    onchange = "PreencheDadosVendedor(this, 3, '" + @Model.ServicosID + "')" });
                                                               ^____                     ^____
```

Or better do this, instead of adding an `onchange` attribute; attach an event instead and make use of `data-*` attributes to store element specific values, this way you separate out html and js:

i.e:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumTransportado, 
                      new { @class = "form-control input-sm myclass", //Add a class  
                        id = "NumTransResp" + Model.ServicosID + "",
                        data_tipoFuncionario = 3, //Add a data attribute 
                        name = "NumTransResp" + Model.ServicosID + ""});
```

and

```
$('.myclass').change(function(e){
     var idServicoEdicao = this.id.replace("NumTransResp",""),  //get the part from its own id
         tipoFuncionario = $(this).data("tipoFuncionario"); //get the value from data attribute

     $.getJSON("/Contrato/getDadosVendedor", { id: this.value, tipoFuncionario: tipoFuncionario },
 function (result) {
      switch (tipoFuncionario) {
          case 1:
              $("#NomeVendedor_Contrato").val(result.NomeVendedor);
          case 2:
              $("#NomeTransResponsavel").val(result.NomeVendedor);
          case 3:
              $("#NomeTransResponsavel_" + idServicoEdicao).val(result.NomeVendedor);
      }
  });

});
```